# Multiplas conexões com o Banco

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Em um sistema PHP que se comunica com o BD (MySQL) para recuperar as informações e retorna-las ao usuário que o acessa é necessário estabelecer múltiplas conexões com o Banco? Ou somente uma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diz o manual do PHP que ...

> A conexão com o servidor será fechada assim que a execução do script
>   terminar, a menos que tenha sido fechada anteriormente usando-se
>   explicitamente...

Verdade, mas não 100%. Não nos podemos esquecer do lado do servidor pode existir definições como **Connection Lifetime** ou **Connection pooling**.

De forma simplista a uma instância correspoderá uma conexão à base de dados. Hoje em dia e a partir da versão 5 do PHP, a utilização da biblioteca PDO, permite de forma implicita utilizar a gestão da conexão à base de dados, reaproveitando a mesma "conexão" a cada **HTTP Request** consequente.

Desta forma e no caso de um acesso simples de uma instância a uma base de dados é pacifico, mas a localização geográfica de ambos os pontos vai interferir, como o tempo que decorrer entre **Request**.

Se formos um pouco mais a fundo na questão percebemos que lidar com a criação de uma conexão é um processo lento. E por isso é que ao invés de fazer uma nova conexão para cada solicitação, o servidor **SQL utiliza uma POOL** de, digamos a titulo de exemplo, 100 conexões "ativas/permanentes".

Na prática você no PHP quando precisa de uma conexão, solicita-a (instanciando o PDO) e usa, e usa... Você pode ajustar o tamanho da POOL para mudar a forma como o seu aplicativo se comporta. `Maior POOL` = `mais conexões` = `mais "threads"` permitindo fazer mais "coisas" ao mesmo tempo, mas isso também pode sobrecarregar o lado do servidor.

Ao escrever estas linhas vem um projeto recente à memória onde...

A uma instância do objecto PDO irá corresponder a uma conexão à base de dados, mas várias instâncias podem utilizar as mesmas conexões quando a implementação *"salte"* permanentemente entre base de dados como por exemplo num mecanismo de **Sharding**, mais precisamente em *FEDERATED TABLE*. Trata-se de um mecanismo muito simples pois a base mantém-se onde a reutilização de conexões cabe ao servidor gerir, sendo que pode *e deve* o seu código ser um pouco inteligente e dar uma ajuda.

Na prática resulta em instâncias do PDO entre "requets consecutivos". Mais uma vez e na prática é mantido o mecanismo de uma instância do "objeto" para uma conexão, mas não necessariamente conexões distintas se por exemplo um servidor alojar várias base de dados ou em casos em que o request utiliza o mesmo servidor de um request anterior.

Os recursos não são infindáveis e é por isso que chamamos servidor a um servidor/serviço de SQL, pois além de "arrumar" a informação, tem também a seu cargo muitas outras tarefas como a de gerir e optimizar as conexões.

Answer (score 4):

No seu código apenas uma basta.

O que pode ocorrer é sua aplicação ser chamadas múltiplas vezes pelo mesmo usuário ou usuários diferentes. Seriam várias instâncias da aplicação, cada uma vai estabelecer uma conexão própria com o banco de dados. Então neste cenário o banco de dados estará atrelado à várias sessões de comunicação de dados com as instâncias da aplicação.

Mas cada instância só precisa ter uma conexão, não importa quantas coisas diferentes você queira fazer com no banco de dados.

Isto não quer dizer que não possa ter várias conexões. Se houver um motivo para ter várias, não há problema também.

Em alguns casos a conexão permanece aberta mas em estado de espera, então quando a mesma instância manda criar uma nova conexão que foi "fechada" ela aproveita a conexão já existente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Apenas uma por banco de dados. Normalmente você irá abrir a conexão no início do processamento da requisição, e esta irá ser reaproveitada até o final.

Algo como:

1. Inicia a execução do script;
2. Chama o script de configuração;
3. Inclui demais scripts necessários;
4. Abre conexão com o banco;
5. Executa queries;
6. Gera a resposta da requisição (HTML, XML, Json, JPG, ou qualquer outra coisa);
7. Encerra a conexão;
8. Fim do script.

Em alguns casos você pode querer que a conexão seja persistente entre várias requisições, mas desconheço de um caso onde isso será útil. Verifique a documentação do driver utilizado para verificar o suporte a este recurso.

Algumas características do driver que você utilizar poderão influenciar no ciclo de vida da conexão.

Por exemplo, o driver PDO irá manter a conexão aberta até que o destrutor do objeto seja chamado (atribuindo `null` à referência do objeto).

Outros drivers, como o `pg` irá fechar a conexão ou quando uma chamada a `pg_close` acontecer ou quando encerrar a execução do script. Do contrário, chamadas ao `pg_connect` irão reaproveitar conexões criadas, desde que a string de conexão seja a mesma.

**Observação:** Sei que colocou a tag `mysql` na sua questão, mas ela é um tanto genérica. Acabei citando o PostgreSQL por eu ter mais experiência com ele.

Comment: Seria uma conexão por requisição, então se dois usuarios fizerem 10 requisições cada serão abertas e fechadas 20 conexões, ou poderia aproveitar a mesma conexão durante o tempo em que o usuario ficar logado?

Comment: O ideal, por incrível que pareça, é abrir e fechar as 20 conexões, uma por requisição (pelo menos nos casos tradicionais). O motivo disso, é que uma conexão aberta consome recursos do servidor, o que pode causar inclusive problemas de DoS (imagine se ao invés de 2 usuários, fossem 2000 usuários... seriam 2000 conexões mantidas abertas a todo momento!). Além disso, normalmente o banco de dados esta "próximo" do servidor web, e portanto a conexão pode ser estabelcida em meros milissegundos, ou menos.

Comment: Entendi, Obrigado