# Manter conexão aberta em webservice php

Tags: php, web-service, pdo

Estou construindo um simples webservice e PHP + JSON onde tenho 2 tabelas e pretendo efetuar as operações de CRUD. É possível que o webservice seja a médio prazo consumido por muitos dispositivos ao mesmo tempo, o que na minha opinião pode acarretar em muitas conexões simultâneas. O servidor possui um limite de conexões ativas determinado pelo pessoal da infra (acho que são 30).
Minha dúvida é, eu utilizo o PDO para abrir a conexão  e a conexão é chamada por um método estático, em cada requisição eu recebo o ID do usuário que faz a consulta, é melhor mudar o modo como a conexão é realizada sempre abrindo e fechando a cada consulta ou isso não vai afetar o número de conexões abertas?
Segue um trecho da minha classe de conexão:

```
class Database extends PDO {

    /**
     * @var array Array of saved databases for reusing
     */
    protected static $instances = array();

    /**
     * Static method get 
     * 
     * @param  array $group
     * @return \helpers\database
     */
    public static function get ($group = false) {
        // Determining if exists or it's not empty, then use default group defined in config
        $group = !$group ? array (
            'type' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'name' => 'banco',
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => 'toor'
        ) : $group;

        // Group information
        $type = $group['type'];
        $host = $group['host'];
        $name = $group['name'];
        $user = $group['user'];
        $pass = $group['pass'];

        // ID for database based on the group information
        $id = "$type.$host.$name.$user.$pass";

        // Checking if the same 
        if(isset(self::$instances[$id])) {
            return self::$instances[$id];
        }

        try {
            // I've run into problem where
            // SET NAMES "UTF8" not working on some hostings.
            // Specifiying charset in DSN fixes the charset problem perfectly!
            $instance = new Database("$type:host=$host;dbname=$name", $user, $pass);
            $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // Setting Database into $instances to avoid duplication
            self::$instances[$id] = $instance;

            return $instance;
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            //in the event of an error record the error to errorlog.html
            Logger::newMessage($e);
            logger::customErrorMsg();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pergunta pertinente. Parte da resposta está nesta minha resposta no seguinte link aqui no SO...

[Multiplas conexões com o Banco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44671/multiplas-conex%C3%B5es-com-o-banco/44802#44802)

Acrescentaria que a sua implementação contempla e muito bem array static com as conexões estabelecidas em um request. Boa solução quando um request utiliza a classe Database mais do que uma vez.

No caso de requests sucessivos existem técnicas com referência em cache server mas nem sempre está disponível. Eu utilizo o **memcached**. No entanto penso que optimizar o servidor para lidar com o problema será o melhor. Como disse dá uma leitura na minha resposta que coloquei aqui o link.